# \date{} in the tabular environment!

Tags: latex

I would like to make a table using the tabular environment, and in one of the cells in my table I need to include the actual date. A clever approach would then be using the \date{} command - but I cannot make it work to include the \date{} command inside the tabular environment...is that not possible??

Cheers,

Karsten

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`\date` doesn't get the date, it sets the date of the document.  If you browse the `latex.ltx` source code you find:

```
\def\date#1{\gdef\@date{#1}}
```

So if the date of the document is set in the preamble, you can get it by using `\@date`.  Unfortunately (for you) that macro has an `@` in it so you can't use it directly in regular document text.  So you would have to put this in your preamble:

```
\makeatletter
\let\insertdate\@date
\makeatother
```

Then `\insertdate` is an alias to `\@date` and will insert the date specified in the preamble into the current text.

But you also mentioned the "actual" date, which may mean the *current* date as of the compilation of the document.  That information is stored by TeX in `\today`.

BTW, You can find an entire community on the [TeX StackExchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/), where no TeX-related question is too small.

Comment: @Karsten: glad it worked. You might also consider editing the question for posterity.  For instance, was it `\insertdate` or `\today` that was the answer to your real question?

Answer (score 0):

You can put the following in the preambule

```
\usepackage{datetime}
\newdateformat{bkdate}{\THEYEAR-\shortmonthname-\twodigit{\THEDAY}}
```

and then print the date anywhere in the document body

```
\bkdate\today
```